# Rails: Select where return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a *store* and an *item* table. 
Before saving an item record I want to get the store id that belongs to the current user. I tried doing this:

```
@item.store_id = Store.select("id").where(:user_id => current_user.id )
```

But the store_id is always nil. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: try `current_user.stores`, if u have proper association. Add breakpoint in your `action` and check output of this query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that User belongs to store and that Item belongs to store:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Then you can access the associations more directly:

```
@item.store = current_user.store
```

Comment: why do I need to add the "belongs_to :store" to the user? what I currently have: "has_many :items belongs_to :user" in the store. And "belongs_to :store belongs_to :user" to the item.

Comment: So a user can have many stores?  How do you determine which of the user's stores should be associated with the item?